# Deploy django project on microsoft 2008 server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, deployment, windows-server-2008

I have a django 1.6 project connecting to an existing remote mssql server using Django MSSQL Database Backend. The Python version is 2.7 in virtualenv. I want to deploy this project onto a windows 2008 server. I searched the solution for a long time but no one seems fit my situation. I am pretty new to Django and this is my first deployment. I appreciate if someone could contribute some ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

firstly I'd suggest hosting your app on www.pythonanywhere.com ( it provides free Django and Python hosting ).

It supports virtualenv and many other features. Additionally I would suggest you use Python3.4 and Django1.8 unless you're set on using the legacy systems. Databases can be accessed using different Python and Django versions.

Lastly if you're learning just go over the entire tutorial step by step and you'll be amazed at what you can do.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

All you need to do is follow the tutorial while implementing it in realtime on the pythonanywhere server. You'll be great at it in no time !
Good luck !

Comment: Hi- pythonanywhere dev here. just to clarify, we do not offer a hosting solution on a windows 2008 server. Instead it runs on a linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IIS (IIS7 and up) with FCGI to deploy your Django project.

FCGI Support is deprecated since Django 1.7 but there is an FCGI-WSGI Bridge that can be used:
http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/06/27/running-django-under-windows-with-iis-using-fcgi/

I have used this approach with Django 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 successfully under MS Server 2008 and 2012.